# Pandas dataframe keeps adding to existing

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code which is setting a dataframe from an excel list which I am then copying out to a new file and saving as .xml which is all good. The problem is when I run the script again its as if the dataframe content just adds the to existing variable and it doesnt get reset. So therefore, the xml file, even if it is saved with a new name and path gets all the old data added to the bottom. I have checked whether deleting the old data and or saving the workbook with new data resets it but it doesnt seem to.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from progress.bar import IncrementalBar
#setting pd options
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

#variables
path = (r"C:\\Users\\ciara\\desktop\\")
book = os.path.join(path + "Search_Set.xlsm")
df1 = pd.read_excel(book, "<CLEAN>", header=None)

#added to remove 0 line from df
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0]
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
df1.columns.name = None

#df property
df1.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})


bar = IncrementalBar('Processing', max=100)
for i in range(100):
    fyle= open("C:\\Users\\ciara\\desktop\\Hope1.xml", "a+")
    fyle.write(df1.to_string(justify='left', index=False))
    fyle.close()
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

Comment: The code as written will append to the file `C:\Users\ciara\desktop\Hope1.xml` because you open the file with the `"a"` mode.  Do you intend to overwrite the file instead of appending to it?

Comment: Yep, the scripts intended purpose is to overwrite the existing file!

Comment: changed it to "w" and did the trick, thanks @PaSTE